# rqt: a tabcontrol container for plugins

Tags: plugin, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I really like rqt with its plugin system.
My rqt plugins are growing in numbers and can no longer coexist in one view.
Has anyone created a tab control where multiple rqt plugins can be organized on each tab?
I would like that kind of quick switching between views.

It is probably not that difficult, if it wasn't because I am quite unexperienced with qt development.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275582/rqt:-a-tabcontrol-container-for-plugins/) by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 811 on 2017-11-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rqt` uses Qt dock widgets to implement the UI. Those are out-of-the-box able to be dragged-n-dropped. Beside rerepositioning them within the main windows you can "drop" them on another widget and they will change into a tab view. You can also "drop" them outside the main window to make them floating.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2017-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on 2017-11-10**:
Hmmm, I tried a lot before and after asking the question, but now I finally managed to drop a widget in the right spot. It was not easy and rqt crashed several times. Also I was fooled by the fact that the tabs appear in the bottom. But thanks a lot for the answer.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2017-11-10**:
If you can reproduce the crash it might be worth filling a ticket. Maybe it can be fixed...